# Accessing Label's texture_size property in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to implement a line wrap function for Kivy's `TextInput`. I'm creating a `Label` inside my wrapping function and checking its texture size to see if the line needs wrapping. But the `texture_size` property returns `[0,0]` regardless of the text. So I've put together a little test code to investigate:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        def f(a):
            print(l.texture_size)
        l = Label(text="Random text")
        t = Button(on_press = f)
        print(l.texture_size)
        return t

Test().run()
```

The `texture_size` returns `[0,0]` when printed from the `build` method, however the button prints the correct value. A button is not an option in my case, I'd like to create a `Label`, get its texture size and pretty much delete it. Maybe there is a better way to determine text size in pixels for a specific font? Or, if not, why doesn't it print the correct value inside the `build` method?

Comment: There's an internal class used for actually rendering text to a texture. I'd find that (probably kivy.core.text.something) and use it to render then check the texture size. You may be running into a timing problem if the texture isn't created immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting the `text` property, you have to refresh the core label and check its texture size:

```
my_label = Label()
my_label.text = 'hello'
my_label._label.refresh()
print my_label._label.texture.size
>>> (33, 18)

my_label.text = 'goodbye'
my_label._label.refresh()
print my_label._label.texture.size
>>> (57, 18)
```

Keep in mind that this accesses a protected attribute, so no guarantee is made that this API will remain consistent in future versions.

Also, we recently merged a [PR to add text wrapping support for long lines](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4055) to `TextInput`. You might try the [development version of Kivy](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html#development-version) and see if it does what you need!